# Trato traer el indice de un array pero me sale undefined

Tags: array, reactjs

Estoy practicando React para crear un pequeña App de una lista de tareas. Cree una función que me permite indicar como completadas las tareas al darle clic al check pero al momento de darle en lugar de cambiar el estado de false a true (el check se pone de color verde) me salta un error en consola de que el array al que quiero acceder esta undefined. Paso código y repositorio:

- `completeTodo`:  es una función flecha que recibe como argumento un texto (que es el texto de la tarea), que contiene la variable `todoIndex`.
- `todoIndex` es una variable que contiene el valor del estado(todos) aplicando el método `findIndex()` para que si el texto del todo coincida con el texto me devuelva el indice.
- `newTodos` es la variable que contiene los *todos* ya guardados previamente en el estado de *todos*.

Al valor de newTodos hago el llamado del índicE[todoIndex] y establezco que a esta posición, la propiedad `completed` es igual a true. Y luego sencilamente hago la modificación de los valores del estado con `setTodo` y hago el llamado de la función `completeTodo` en el componente que deseo.

Pero me sale `undefined` y salta el error.

Link:
https://github.com/Raru9c/proyecto-react-teorico.git

```
import React from 'react';
import { ToDoCounter } from './TodoDoCounter';
import { TodoItem } from './TodoItem';
import { TodoList } from './TodoList';
import { TodoSearch } from './TodoSearch';
import { CreateTodoButton } from './CreateTodoButton';
//import './App.css';
import "./index.css"

const defaultTodos = [
  {text: 'Comprar comida', completed: true},
  {text: 'Comprar dolares', completed: true},
  {text: 'Comprar insumos', completed: false},
  {text: "Aprender React", completed: true}
];


function App() {

  const [todos, setTodo] = React.useState (defaultTodos);
  const [ searchValue, setSearchValue] = React.useState (""); 

  const completedTodos = todos.filter (todos => !!todos.completed).length;
  const totalTodos = todos.length;

  let searchedTodos = [];

  
  if (!searchValue.length >= 1) {
    searchedTodos = todos;
  } else {
    searchedTodos = todos.filter(todo => {
      const todoText = todo.text.toLowerCase();
      const searchText = searchValue.toLowerCase();
      return todoText.includes(searchText);
    });
  }

  const completeTodos=(text) => {
    
  const todoIndex= todos.findIndex(todo => todo.text === text);
    
    // todos[todoIndex]= {
    //   text: todos [todoIndex].text,
    //   completed: true
    // }

  const newTodos = [...todos];
  newTodos[todoIndex].completed=true;
  setTodo (newTodos)
  
  
};

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
    <ToDoCounter
    totalTodos={totalTodos}
    completed={completedTodos}
    />
    <TodoSearch
      searchValue={searchValue} 
      setSearchValue={setSearchValue}
    />
    <TodoList>
     {searchedTodos.map (todo => (
      <TodoItem  
      key={todo.text}  
      text={todo.text}
      completed={todo.completed} 
      onComplete= {() => completeTodos(todos.text)}
      />
     ))}
    </TodoList>
    <CreateTodoButton/>
    </React.Fragment>


    

  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Este es el error `Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'completed')` ?

Comment: Si, ese es el error que me salta al intentar ejecutar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con ojo de aguila pude ver tu error:

Estas mandando el texto de manera incorrecta en TodoItem:

Tienes esto

```
<TodoItem
  key={todo.text}
  text={todo.text}
  completed={todo.completed}
  onComplete={() => completeTodos(todos.text)} // ACA ESTAS HACIENDO todos.text PERO TODOS ES UN ARRAY
/>
```

Cambiar a:

```
<TodoItem
  key={todo.text}
  text={todo.text}
  completed={todo.completed}
  onComplete={() => completeTodos(todo.text)}
/>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Efectivamente, ese era el error.